# Dynamic values for Form Flow elements

Tags: botframework

I'm building a form and I understand that we can prompt user to choose from a list of options by using enums. But enums are fixed, So is there a way where we can use a dynamically generated list (it's a compile time generated entity) instead of enums?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use the fluent API to do this. Use the `Advanced.Field.SetDefine` to define a delegate that will be used to add dynamically generated values to the field. 
Have a look at the [Dynamic Fields](http://docs.botframework.com/sdkreference/csharp/forms.html#dynamicFields) documentation

```
                        .Field(new FieldReflector<SandwichOrder>(nameof(Specials))
                        .SetType(null)
                        .SetActive((state) => state.Length == LengthOptions.FootLong)
                        .SetDefine(async (state, field) =>
                        {
                            field
                                .AddDescription("cookie", "Free cookie")
                                .AddTerms("cookie", "cookie", "free cookie")
                                .AddDescription("drink", "Free large drink")
                                .AddTerms("drink", "drink", "free drink");
                            return true;
                        }))
```